# WCF: relativeAddress,baseAddress and binding

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I am new in WCF and start my experience with a simple file-less application part of which (web.config) you can see below:

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add
                factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
                relativeAddress="./RelativeAddress.svc"
                service="WCF_Transactions.MyService1"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Now I can access service at

```
http://localhost:18148/RelativeAddress.svc
```

Then I add next lines:

```
    <services>
        <service name="WCF_Transactions.MyService1" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior1">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:18148/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint  address="/RelativeAddressX.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Transactions.IService1"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyBehavior1">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

So I expect that my service could be accessible through next address:

```
  http://localhost:18148/RelativeAddressX.svc
```

but I can't do this. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: What is the type of hosting, you use? Is it IIS or self-hosting?

Comment: I use visual studio development server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx:
*

> There are two ways to specify endpoint addresses for a service in WCF.
>   You can specify an absolute address for each endpoint associated with
>   the service or you can provide a base address for the ServiceHost of a
>   service and then specify an address for each endpoint associated with
>   this service that is defined relative to this base address. You can
>   use each of these procedures to specify the endpoint addresses for a
>   service in either configuration or code. If you do not specify a
>   relative address, the service uses the base address.

*
So according to your example you have base adress

```
 http://localhost:18148/
```

and it will be combined with RelativeAddress.svc, as a name of your svc file. And then it will try to combine this string with /RelativeAddressX.svc as a part of endpoint adress. So you will have something like

```
 http://localhost:18148/RelativeAddress.svc/RelativeAddressX.svc.
```

Your endpoint must not specify the path to svc in IIS. It should containg only a logical adress, assosiated with this point.
So try to change your endpoint to the following:

```
 <endpoint  address="RelativeAddressX" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Transactions.IService1"></endpoint>
```

And it should be accessible by the path

```
 http://localhost:18148/RelativeAddress.svc/RelativeAddressX
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify  in the config file when hosting in IIS or Cassini - the base URL is provided by the web server. The  element is used when self-hosting. Cassini (VS build in web-server) will ignore it.

Here is a good page about WCF addressing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx

Here are some related posts:
[WCF Service Endpoints vs Host Base address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937853/wcf-service-endpoints-vs-host-base-address)
[WCF, changing the baseAdress of an endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909332/wcf-changing-the-baseadress-of-an-endpoint)